# Showing a JIRA Query in Confluence page

Tags: jira, confluence

I have a JIRA query which I've made public:

[image]

I then have a confluence page which I want to add this query to, but when I search for it it doesn't return anything:

[image]

However, if I paste in the URL it seems to derive the filter id and seems to work:

[image]

What's weird is that whilst this shows for me, my colleagues can't see the results of the query on the page (they can see the page though).

I feel like the two issues could be related, but not sure. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Just to be sure: What does your colleges see then? Are they logged-in in Jira while they visit the Confluence page? Is there the option to login in Jira on the Confluence page? Trust between Confluence and Jira is tricky, and sometimes the way Jira works just does not allow you to share things in Confluence ...

Comment: The colleague see's the Confluence page content and is logged in. They see the a box for the Jira query which says "The project doesn't exist or you don't have access"

Comment: Really oddly, they have loaded the same page today and it seems to work. I believe there may be a delay in changing the permissions of the Jira query (from private to public) and confluence reflecting that change

Answer (score 0):

**First**, regarding the query in Confluence. You can't enter query names in confluence to display issue details, you always have to use [JQL](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/jira-software/jql-the-most-flexible-way-to-search-jira-14) (project = XYZ and ...)

**Second**, regarding issue detail visibility in Confluence:
From my experience in our corporate setup, where Jira and Confluence licences are separated, users how don't have and active Jira licence can't see Jira issues in Confluence. They need to have access to both.
**Additionally**, we restrict project access/manage project permissions using the project roles. If a user has Confluence and Jira, but has no access to the underlying project, he will not see the Jira issues you want to display. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the interface clearly says you can use plain text search, which is a terrible UX :(

Second, all our users have access to both Jira and Confluence at admin level, so they do have permissions, it's just confluence implies they don't. It eventually started working without me doing anything, so I can only assume there is a syncing issue between setting permissions on a query and confluence reflecting those.

Comment: You can use plain text search but only for issues (summary) and not filter names. If you want to use filter name, you need to use JQL this way: `filter = "Phase 3 - Sprint 1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Display options in Jira macro. Came to a reasonable solution
[image]